# Partial derivatives of polynomials in $k[X_1,X_2]$

Tags: polynomials, partial-derivative

Let $f$ and $g$ be two polynomials in $k[X_1,X_2]$ such that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_2} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial X_1}.$$ Is it true that there exists $h$ in $k[X_1,X_2]$ such that $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial X_1} = f \text{ and } \frac{\partial h}{\partial X_2}=g?$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because you define:

$$ h(X_1,X_2)=\int{f(X_1,X_2)dX_1}+A(X_2) $$

First, by definition of $h$ you will have:

$$ \frac{\partial h}{\partial X_1}=f(X_1,X_2). $$

Second, take the other partial derivative:

$$g(X_1,X_2)=\frac{\partial h}{\partial X_2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial X_2}\int{f(X_1,X_2)dX_1}+A^{\prime}(X_2)$$

so, you isolate $A^{\prime}(X_2)$

$$ A^{\prime}(X_2)=g(X_1,X_2)-\frac{\partial }{\partial X_2}\int{f(X_1,X_2)dX_1}  $$

finallly

$$ A(X_2)=\int{\left(g(X_1,X_2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial X_2}\int{f(X_1,X_2)dX_1}\right)}dX_2 + K $$
where $K$ is a constant (not depending neither $X_1$ nor $X_2$).

**The difference between two differents primitives of a function is always a constant. That explains why the following expression is not always zero (like I said in a previous version):
$$ g(X_1,X_2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial X_2}\int{f(X_1,X_2)dX_1}\neq 0 $$**
**In fact, for your example $f=1+X_2$ and $g=1+X_1$ the difference above equals 1.**

The final formula can be written as:

$$ h(X_1,X_2)=\int{f(X_1,X_2)dX_1}+\int{\left(g(X_1,X_2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial X_2}\int{f(X_1,X_2)dX_1}\right)}dX_2 + K$$

Also, starting with:

$$h(X_1,X_2)=\int{g(X_1,X_2)dX_2}+B(X_1)$$

we find that:

$$ B^{\prime}(X_1)=f(X_1,X_2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial X_1}\int{g(X_1,X_2)dX_2} $$

so

$$ B(X_1)=\int{\left(f(X_1,X_2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial X_1}\int{g(X_1,X_2)dX_2}\right)}dX_1+C $$

Finally

$$h(X_1,X_2)=\int{g(X_1,X_2)dX_2}+\int{\left(f(X_1,X_2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial X_1}\int{g(X_1,X_2)dX_2}\right)}dX_1+C.$$

Comment: Clear and neat! Many thanks.

Comment: Your welcome :)

Comment: Hey, Hector. Do you think the same proof also holds for formal power series with formal differentiation and integration?

Comment: Probably, yes. I think so :)

Comment: Is it obvious that we can interchange differentiation and integration signs, as you did in the 6th line?

Comment: Assuming we work with polynomials yes in a formal sense. With formal series I think you can

Comment: I am sorry but I guess there is something I am missing here. For example, if $f=1+X_2$ and $g=1+X_1$ then $1=\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_2}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial X_1}$. Then $h=X_1+X_1X_2$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial X_1}=f$ but $\frac{\partial h}{\partial X_2}\neq g$, the term $A(X_2)\neq 0$ in this case right?

Comment: Yes, you right. I have to correct my answer :)  I will update l as soon as I can :)

Comment: For the case $f=1+X_2$ and $g=1+X_1$ you have that $$h=X_1+X_2+X_{1}X_{2}$$

Comment: @varphi: I updated the answer :)  I hope it helps !

Comment: @varphi: For the case $f=1+X_2$ and $g=1+X_1$ you have that 
$$h(X_1,X_2)=X_1+X_2+X_1X_2$$

Comment: @varphi: I updated the answer. For instance, in your example $A(X_2)=X_2$ and $B(X_1)=X_1$.

Comment: This whole discussion was great, and really helpful. I believe I have also generalized it to formal power series. Thanks again!

Comment: Your welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is an example in 2D of the fact that the $\nabla \times \nabla \equiv 0$, that is, the curl of the gradient of any scalar function is zero on a domain that is contractible. So, the first equation you gave above says that the curl of the vector $[f,g]$ is zero. Therefore, if the domain is contractible, then $[f,g]$ is in the image of the gradient operator. Therefore, there must exist a scalar, $h$, such that $\nabla h = [f, g]$.

Note that the curl in 2D is defined as follows (up to a minus sign):
$$
 \nabla \times [f,g] := \partial f/\partial y - \partial g/\partial x\;.
$$

Answer (score 1):

No, in positive characteristic. For example, the polynomials $f(x,y) = x$ and $g(x,y) = 0$ have $\partial f/\partial y = \partial g/\partial x$, but in characteristic 2, $f$ is not the $x$-derivative of any polynomial because the power rule falls apart.

Otherwise yes, consult any multivariate calculus textbook for how to do it, as demonstrated in other answers.